# How to trigger airflow dag from shell script

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, hana, sap-bw

I have an AutoSys job which will load SAP BW HANA tables. Once loading is done, I should trigger a airflow dag in AutoSys through shell script which will perform data ingestion from SAP BW HANA to AWS s3. Basically I need to trigger airflow dag from shell scripts.

Please share all possibilities. TIA

Answer (score 2):

For triggering a dag, you can use the following command:
`airflow trigger_dag dag-name`

You can find more commands in the airflow documentation:
https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#trigger_dag